# Use separation of variable to find the solution the differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{dz}{dt} = te^z , \text{through  the  origin}  $$

$$\int\frac{dz}{e^z} = \int t dt$$

let $u = e^z  $ so $\frac{du}{dz} = e^{z}$ hence
$$du = e^z dz$$

which i cannot use

How about let $z = e^z$

$$\int\frac{dz}{z} = \int t dt$$
$$ln|z| = t^2$$
$$\sqrt{ln|z|} = t$$

Comment: What is the integral of $\mathrm{e}^{-x}$ with respect to x?

Comment: You wouldn't want to do that $z=e^z$. That would be a total blunder. $z=e^z$, then $dz=e^z\,dz$ and $e^z=1$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac{dz}{e^z}=\int{e^{-z}\,dz}=-e^{-z}+k$$

Answer (score 0):

Letting $z=e^z$ is NOT permitted. In case you want to use substitution you have to change the variable. Secondly for this trivial integral you don't need veteran techniques like substitution. Simple integration rules suffice !!

$\int\dfrac{dz}{e^z}=\int e^{-z}dz=-e^{-z}+c_1$. So your solution is

$-e^{-z}=\dfrac{t^2}{2}+C$.

Look for the table of integration formulae [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_integrals)